# How to run code on exit of a WCF service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I want to run some code just before my WCF service is **destroyed**.

Just as the `AppInitialize()` method put in a class in the `App_Code` folder is run on WCF startup, I'm wondering if there is some similar method run on WCF **exit**?

You guys have any suggestions? Any help is very appreciated.

Additionally I **don't** want to run code on *Session exit* or other similar stuff, but when the service is actually terminated.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  It sounds like your WCF service is hosted in `IIS`? Correct?  If not _how_ is your service hosted.  This will help us help you.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes it's correct, my service is hosted in **IIS**.